# Regex to match where a word does not exist between an opening and closing delimeter

Tags: regex

I want to do a regex search in a project in webstorm ide (java based) and match to lines in some template files that contain a `<panel ........ >` but exclude ones that have the word `narrow`, `medium` or `wide` in between the opening `<panel` and the closing `>`.

The files are very structured and our own internal format so we know exactly what we are having to parse and don't have to worry about being tripped up by attributes with conflicting values.

I know that something like `<panel([^>]+)?` would get me the tags I am interested in but I cant see how to exclude the ones that already have values.

Comment: Please review the [regex tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) and [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28748005/edit) your question accordingly. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically it can be done with a incremental look ahead test on each character
as its matched, until you reach the end.

```
 # <panel(?:(?!narrow|medium|wide)[^>])+>

 <
 panel
 (?:
      (?!
           narrow
        |  medium
        |  wide
      )
      [^>] 
 )+
 >
```

Answer (score 3):

Negative lookahead:

```
<panel(?!narrow)([^>]+)?
```

This can be extended to exclude medium/wide.

Comment: As suggested I extended this answer by piping the values 'narrow|medium|wide' but it doesn't do what I wanted as this still didn't exclude anything. 

Moving the negative look ahead inside the following brackets as in sln's answer above fixed that

This answer was still useful as the first one suggesting a negative look ahead was the way to go, which really was the solution to the problem